# How to make the form non scrollable in sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch

How to make the forms non scrollable in sencha touch? I have not used anything like

```
scrollable:true or scroll: vertical.
```

But i can still drag them down. The entire fieldset moves up and down when dragged. Can anyone please tel me how to fix it?
I have even tried setting

```
scrollable: false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert `scrollable: false` into your component's `config` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. But the form background color became light after that. Why so?

Comment: yes, because CSS style for scrollable and non-scrollable container differ